# What is the reasoning for hidden files in operating systems?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems

On every operating system I have used (Ubuntu, Fedora, Windows, and Mac OS X), there has been a standard for hidden files.  Initially I thought that this feature was simply to hide some files from view when looking at a directory listing, but it seems that this may not be the only reasoning.

What is the reasoning behind an OS having the "feature" of hidden files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Hidden files aren't important.

Oh, of course, they run your OS and store your configuration, so without them you'd be a bit stuck, but you don't need to see them. They're pretty unimportant to you. People care about things that have a use to them, so hiding the things that don't is a good move from a usability standpoint, to reduce information saturation.

Comment: This is an interesting perspective on "importance" of files. Thank you for the mental shift.

Answer (score 6):

One of the main reasons is to avoid [PEBKAC errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) -- inexperienced users deleting and modifying files when they don't know their purpose. If you can do something to save yourself a large percent of support calls, I'd suggest doing it :)

Comment: If you can link back to the original comic strip that introduced the world to PEBKAC, I'll give you +1.

Comment: @Randolph Potter I don't know which one was the original, but this one (and derivatives) have been around for **ages** : http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/7793/pebkaccomicstrip.gif :)

Comment: Good enough for me. That's the one I was thinking of.

Comment: "PICNIC" error, problem in chair not in computer

Comment: That's a new one (to me anyway). I like it.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be: to stop average users from deleting important files.

Answer (score 0):

So if you remove folder with system files then they would be gone too.
Thats for windows. Anyways thats an old bad way.
Not important to know to get computer working.